# Deprecation Warning About Mass Assignment Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am upgrading an app to 4.0 and using ruby-2.2.5. I am down to a couple of Deprecation Warnings, which appear when I run >> bundle exec rake.

One of the warnings:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Model based mass assignment security has been extracted out of Rails into a gem. 
Please use the new recommended protection model for params or add `protected_attributes` to your Gemfile to use the old one.

To disable this message remove the `whitelist_attributes` option from your `config/application.rb` file 
and any `mass_assignment_sanitizer` options from your `config/environments/*.rb` files.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment for more information.
```

I understand what this about and I have gone through all my models looking for and removing 'attr_accessible'.  I have gone through all my controllers and added a method for strong_params, which I call in my 'create' and 'update' actions.  We are not using 'whitelist_attributes' or any 'mass_assignment_sanitizer' options. And, all my spec tests are passing.

My Questions is, Would this warning be just a standard output or would it be from rails seeing something I am not?  Ideas?

Much appreciated

Comment: I think there is a setting for it in one of the environment files, or maybe `application.rb` if you still have that in maybe that's what rails is complaining about

Comment: # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models  >> config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

Comment: >> config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict, in environments/test.rb and in developement.rb.  Commenting those out removes the Deprecation warning.  Thank you j-dexx.  I would not have thought to look there - obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `gem 'protected_attributes', '~>1.1.3'` at your Gemfile, some people say that gem is unnecessary on Rails 4 but it fix the Deprecation, I not sure if is the best solution: https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes